# Spring batch as windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, spring-batch

## INTRODUCTION

I am new to the Spring Batch, but have experience with Spring and Java. I have made my own wrapper to be able to use Java to create windows services. The main API within my wrapper is usable like this way :

```
    try {
        // shutdown is volatile protected boolean of my runner class which is set by my wrapper when stop request occurs
        while (!shutdown) {
            // Action to be done
            log.info("I am running ..."); 
            Thread.sleep(MyConstants.WAIT);
            // End of action
        }
        log.info("Closing daemon thread.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Runtime service error.", ex);
        throw new ServiceException(ex);
    }
```

## PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

The above works very well and I have been able to use it many times for implementing business logic instead of log.info("I am running ...") in various ms windows and Linux services. But now I want to use **Spring Batch + Boot**. So far was able to run business logic via SpringApplication.run(...) but I need to be able to safelly stop it when shutdown and what I am looking of is the best possible way for it.

## QUESTION

Does somebody has an elegant solution for checking shutdown request and correctly shut down spring batch job called via Spring boot ?

## WHAT I HAVE BEEN ABLE TO DEVISE

- Create singleton threadsafe Spring bean Shutdown class handling shutdown status.
- Run SpringApplication.run(...) from new thread T1 created from MAIN.
- Set shutdown property of Shutdown bean via MAIN thread when OS shutdown status.
- Check in each Spring Batch Reader and Transformer shutdown status via Shutdown bean and throw JobInterruptedException to let Spring Batch stop.

I think that this solution should work, but it seems to me overcomplicated and too bloated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve it in more elegant way using the following concept:

- Using @Configuration on my main service to be able to @Inject it's boolean status in readers, processors, writers
- Use JobMonitor to handle jobs